# Copy & paste on VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I couldnt find any code already posted to actually copy the entire row (like a form)

[image]

then pastes at the bottom in the first empty row of the database.

can anyone please help? Thanks

form A6:AY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested from mobile:

```
Sub CopyPaster()

With ActiveSheet
     .Range("A6").EntireRow.Copy
     .Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")+3,1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Plus 3 to account for the two blank cells in column A
End With

End sub
```

Comment: Thanks, when i create a new button do i just copy this code or i need to include anything else?

Comment: That should be it if that’s all you needed. Try it out and let me know if you get the desired outcome.

Comment: It says invalid outside procedure

Comment: Did you put it in a subroutine?

Comment: yeah, still keeps pasting on the same row, when I try to click the second time...

Comment: I updated the code again. The plus 2 should have been plus 3. My apologies

Comment: I will try!! Thanks!!